# Sort data frame based on the prefix of the values within the columns

Tags: r, sorting

I'm a student in engineering in France and i'm doing a projet in R for university. I'm actually looking for doing something specific with my database.

My database looks like that  :

```
      id         grades     std_id               UID
     1004          1         1004        cm1_AZZ_005_LKJ_xxx
     1004          1         1004        cm1_AZZ_002_LKJ_xxx
     1004          0         1004        cm1_AZZ_005_LKJ_xxx
     1004          1         1004        cm1_AZZ_002_LKJ_xxx
     1004          0         1004        cm1_AZZ_002_LKJ_xxx
     1004          1         1004        cm1_AZZ_009_LKJ_xxx
     1004          1         1004        cm1_AZZ_002_LKJ_xxx
     7687          1         0897        cm1_XYZ_457_HGF_xxx
     7687          1         0897        cm1_XYZ_970_HGF_xxx
     7687          1         0897        cm1_XBZ_674_KGH_xxx
     7687          0         0897        cm1_XBZ_987_KGH_xxx
     7687          1         0897        cm1_XBZ_780_KGH_xxx
     ....        .....       ....               .....
```

I would like to sort my database with the values within the column `UID`.

My data base is larger and the values within the `UID` can be different below the data base.

Presently, I'm taking the interval of each different `UID` manually but it's clearly ineffective :

```
list_002 <- new_items[1:7] 
list_003 <- new_items[8:9]
list_005 <- new_items[10:12]
```

As you can see I would like to sort my database just with the prefix of the `UID` and not with all characters.

```
Prefix : cm1_AZZ, cm1_XYZ, cm1_XBZ
```

In my database the `UID` prefix are always (cm1_AZZ, cm1_XYZ, cm1_XBZ) but the suffix can change.

I would like to sort the database in 3 different lists based on `UID` suffix "(cm1_AZZ, cm1_XYZ, cm1_XBZ)" to have 3 different lists and not a different list by each `UID`.

Like that :

```
list_AAZ <- list()
list_XYZ <- list()
list_XBZ <- list()

list_AZZ <- cm1_AZZ_005      list_XYZ <- cm1_XYZ_457 
            cm1_AZZ_002                  cm1_XYZ_970
            cm1_AZZ_005
            cm1_AZZ_002
            cm1_AZZ_002
            cm1_AZZ_009
            cm1_AZZ_002

list_X4Z <- cm1_XBZ_674
            cm1_XBZ_987
            cm1_XBZ_780
```

Thank for helping me. Sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Split `UID` into 3 columns using for example `tidyr::separate()`, then `split()`, then `sort()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `split` and `sub` you could do:

```
# original answer (before question update):
# new_list <- split(df, sub("(cm1_\\d{3}).*", "\\1", df$UID))
# updated answer:
new_list <- split(df, sub("(cm1_[^_]+).*", "\\1", df$UID))
```

This will return a list where each set of UID-group (excluding suffix) is a data.frame.

You can then access the elements for example using

```
new_list$cm1_AZZ
```

or

```
new_list[[2]]
```

Comment: Thank you @docendo, it's works but I think I don't ask the question correctly. I edited my post.

Comment: @SofianeM'barki, for your update, you can try it with `split(df, sub("(cm1_[^_]+).*", "\\1", df$UID))` instead

Comment: It works perfectly ! Thanks a lot @docendodiscimus. Good continuation !